# Using Exception to avoid yahoofinance error

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I'm simply trying to use an exception to handle HTTPErrors for items like 'FB' to continue iterating through the list but I can't seem to get around the issue. Code:

```
stcks = ['AXSM', 'FB', 'AAPL']
   for i in stcks:
        try: 
            sec = yf.Ticker(i).info['sector']
        except yf.utils.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
            print('error')
            continue
        else: 
            print('hi')
```

Output

```
hi
HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/FB?modules=summaryProfile%2CfinancialData%2CquoteType%2CdefaultKeyStatistics%2CassetProfile%2CsummaryDetail&ssl=true
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
AttributeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[243], line 5
      3 try    : 
      4     sec = yf.Ticker(i).info['sector']
    ----> 5 except yf.utils.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
      6     print('error')
      7     continue

AttributeError: module 'yfinance.utils' has no attribute 'exceptions'
```

How can I get the desired output provided that I cannot get data for one of the items in the list?:

```
hi
hi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `requests` exception to catch missing tickers (`HTTPError`):

```
import requests

stcks = ['AXSM', 'FB', 'AAPL']
for i in stcks:
    try: 
        sec = yf.Ticker(i).info['sector']
    except requests.HTTPError as err:
        print('error')
        continue
    else: 
        print('hi')
```

Output:

```
hi
error
hi
```